# Datar - summarise count python using the datar package(dplyr)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I cant seem to find a way to summarise count on a dataframe

```
from datar.all import *

df = tibble(a=c("a","b","a","b","a"),b=c(1,1,None,1,2))

df >> group_by(f.a) >> summarise(distinct=n_distinct(f.b) ,total_by_group=n())

         a  distinct  total_by_group
  <object>   <int64>         <int64>
0        a         2               3
1        b         1               2
```

However when i tried to do a count on the same column I m getting an error, where I m would expect to see the value count excluding the None - using n() only gives the row count which I m not interested about

```
    df >> group_by(f.a) >> summarise(count(f.b))
NotImplementedByCurrentBackendError: 'count' (data type: SeriesGroupBy, backends: numpy, pandas)
```

What i would like to see is

```
         a  distinct  total_by_group count
  <object>   <int64>         <int64> <int64> 
0        a         2               3 2
1        b         1               2 2
```

Comment: This isn't valid python syntax?

Comment: What is this `>>`? Also, are you looking for this? `df %>% group_by(a) %>%count()`

Comment: This is from a a library called datar and that reproduces dplyr in python, so the syntax is valid.